# How to add the sku to the url key? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, products

The products we sell are unique, but share the same name. So when we add two different products with the same name, it throws back the error that that URL already exists.

What I wanted to do was add the SKU to the URL key. That way it would always have a unique value. But I don't want to have to manually add it each time.

Is there a way to add this in the back end? Similar to the `Configuration/Catalog/Catalog` section allows for adding the `{{sku}}` to the meta tags etc?

Answer (score 5):

I need the same behaviour, i need to have product's sku at the end of product's url, because many products have same name.

So, i created a custom module to override `/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlPathGenerator.php` where in `prepareProductUrlKey()` i changed

```
return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() : $urlKey);
```

to

```
return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() . "-" . $product->getSku() : $urlKey);
```

with product's sku added at the url key end.

Answer (score 2):

Based on LucScu answer I created my own module wich can be helpful to you as well, the file essential to it are the `di.xml` inside `app/code/Developer/Module/etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator" type="Developer\Module\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator" />
</config>
```

and `ProductUrlPathGenerator.php` inside app/code/Developer/Module/model

```
<?php 
namespace FivePreview\URLRewrite\Model;

/**
 * Class AbstractAction
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
*/

class ProductUrlPathGenerator extends \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator {

    protected function prepareProductDefaultUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $storedProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
        $storedUrlKey = $storedProduct->getUrlKey();
        return $storedUrlKey ?: $product->formatUrlKey($storedProduct->getName() . "-" . $storedProduct->getSku());
    }



    protected function prepareProductUrlKey(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $urlKey = $product->getUrlKey();
        return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() . "-" . $product->getSku() : $urlKey);

    }
}
```

and then of course you have to add the `registration.php` in `app/code/Developer/Module` and the `module.xml` inside `app/code/Developer/Module/etc` if you want it to disable/enable